# my font size is 0 byte after launching the app

Tags: android, fonts

I have trouble with my font.

I need to display plain, bold and italic text in a specific font in the same textView.
I use html.fromHtml and with the regular android font it works fine.

I want helvetica instead, so I built a single font file witch contained the three fonts (plain bold italic), and used setTypeFace on my textView. I built it from 3 otf files with fontBuilder.

But when I call `Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/HelveticaNeue.dfont");`
i saw that my font file size was 0 bytes, and indeed in my project I can't import it well,
when i go in the folder fonts i see that the size is ok, but from eclipse point of view, 0 bytes.

Does somebody have an idea ?

ANSWER:

The problem was that my font didn't had **dataFork**, it's a thing that you have to add to your font for it to be understood by PC's, and Unix OS.

Answer (score 1):

is it correct format `.dfont`

i think fonts should be with `.ttf`

```
Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/HelveticaNeue.ttf")
```

Comment: i tried with an other dfont file and it works fine, I think that it may be a problem with the file though. even before compilation, eclipse believe that the file size is 0 bytes

Comment: May be check it first, actually for font types we are using .ttf files.

Comment: ttf can encapsulate several fonts ?